# Calculate full years and partial months between 2 dates

Tags: sql, datediff

I'd like to know how to calculate full years and number of full months between two dates and combine them into one column:

Ex:  My beginning date is a column named "TransferDate" = 7/1/2017 and Today (11/14/2019)  My desired output would be a column named "Age" = **2.3**

2 Full Years (2017 - 2019)
.3 Full Months (August, September & October)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  How do you define "full month"?  Is Feb 28th a "full month" after Jan 31st?

Comment: You'll want to get the date difference in months between the first day of the next month after the TransferDate and the first day of current month. How you do that is dependent upon your language/version.

Comment: On the month calculation of Is Feb 28th a full month after Jan 31st it's a "Yes".  Maybe it's just better to say the calculation shouldn't take into consideration of the current month.  That's why my example calculation only shows through October and not November.  I hope that makes sense.  I don't have a database to tag either.  I can get the months DATEDIFF(MONTH,TransferDate,GETDATE()) as 'Months' but my desired output is a little more detailed than that.  Thanks for the patience

Comment: what if the difference is 10 months?  0.10 ? same with 11 months?

Comment: when the difference is 11 months, do you want the output to be x.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look and see if this gives you what you are looking for.

```
Declare @date1 date = '11/01/2001'
Declare @date2 date = '12/01/2002'

Select @date1
    ,@date2
    ,Case 
    when datediff(M,@date1,@date2) < 12 then ''
    when datediff(M,@date1,@date2) < 24  then 'one year'
    else cast(floor(datediff(M,@date1,@date2)/12) as varchar(20)) + ' Years'
    end  +  ' ' +
Case 
    when datediff(M,@date1,@date2) - floor(datediff(M,@date1,@date2)/12)*12 = 0  then ''
    when datediff(M,@date1,@date2) - floor(datediff(M,@date1,@date2)/12)*12 = 1 then 'one month'
    else cast(datediff(M,@date1,@date2) - floor(datediff(M,@date1,@date2)/12)*12 as varchar(20)) + ' Months'
    end
```

Comment: This did it!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This combines the year and month components into a single column after calculating them as monthdif and yeardif.

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '07/01/2017'
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '11/14/2019'

select CAST((CAST(x.yeardif as nvarchar(20)) + '.' + CAST(x.monthdif as nvarchar(20))) as decimal(5,2)) from
(select DATEDIFF(yyyy,@start,@end) yeardif,DATEDIFF(m,@start,@end) - (12 * DATEDIFF(yyyy,@start,@end)) - 1 monthdif) x
```